# Cost of using waypoints affected only by distance?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The cost of waypoints varies according to the distance from your current point to the selected waypoint.

I'm finding them more expensive each time. Now traveling to a near waypoint (near as in next to it) costs 85 copper. I'm not sure of how much did they cost when I started playing, but I find them increasing in price.

Is it just me? can anyone confirm this? Maybe the cost increases each level, or depending on the area, I'm not sure, but there's something else than distance to calculate the cost.

Comment: It costs me about 4 silver each teleport when I go across the map (at lvl 80).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cost of using waypoints varies with both distance *and* character level.

Once you get up near 80, it'll cost about a silver to go the very first waypoint you unlocked, in your racial starting area (down from 7 copper when you just started out).

Comment: How annoying. I'm convinced this introduction of 'a price for everything' is just some sly attempt to drive micro-transactions...

Comment: @BunjiquoBianco It's a money sink, yes. But money sinks are good for the game as a whole. The alternative is hyperinflation, where you can easily get wherever you want to go, but a single piece of copper ore costs 2-3 gold.

Comment: I just think constant 'taxation' adds to the grind that they've allegedly reduced. Low level materials never got stupidly expensive in GW1, although they were less important I suppose. Anyway, this is probably not the place for an extended discussion on game economics :P

Comment: @BunjiquoBianco I would consider bolts of jute now selling for 62copper per piece and copper ingot selling for 40copper pretty inflated for a low lvl material considering they are about double and triple the cost of material one or two lvl above it.

Comment: @Jay I think that's the heavy demand due to the game being in its infancy and the majority of players being low lvl. Actually, do you get trend graphs for all item prices in the shop? I know you get one for gems...

Comment: @BunjiquoBianco You can find trend graphs for all items here:
http://www.gw2db.com/trading-post